# What is the typical resistance of a DC motor carbon brush

Tags: brushed-dc-motor

This question discusses the fact that DC motor carbon brushes typically have a "high resistance", but it does not address what that resistance is.

[Why is it an advantage that carbon brushes have 'high resistance'?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492161/why-is-it-an-advantage-that-carbon-brushes-have-high-resistance)

With the following brushes, what sort of resistance would be measured between the brass contact at the far end of the assembly and the commutator on the armature of the motor?

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DYW5ZY7?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DYW5ZY7)

Comment: It varies depending on how much current is flowing. Something to do with semiconduction maybe? It was a pain to measure until I figured this out. As for actual resistance it depends on brush size which correlates with motor size/amps rating. On a 4kW generator it was 0.3-0.5 0Ohms.

Comment: @DKNguyen generators generally do not use high resistance brushes.  If you study the question I linked, it explains why high resistance is necessary for a DC motor that uses commutator.  Generators tend to use slip rings therefore there isn't a requirement for high resistance.

Comment: The article you linked said tens of milliohms, and that seems about right.  much more resistance than copper, but not much nonetheless.